# How to add a lots of list items in a different list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I was creating a list python file. There I created a lot of list and adding new items and lists everyday. I wanted to create a list that will have all the items of previous lists automatically. What should I do?

```
list_1=['1','one','first',etc...] 
list_2=['2','two', 'second', '2nd', etc]
.
.
list_x=['x', 'cross']
all_list=list_1+list_2+....+list_x+...   #this will update automatically
```

How to do it?

Comment: This is not possible. You should track the changes yourself and concatenate the lists as shown in your code or track additions and deletions separately and update `all_list` accordingly.

Comment: It feels to me you should not use a list if your program runs for a long period of time. Instead, why not use a database?

Comment: Actually I was creating a command list. And import it to a mini AI program. So I need them in different variables and a ll in a single variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to collect all lists, this code can do the job.

```
def generate_list():
    l = [globals()[name] for name in globals().keys() if name.startswith('list_')]
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

list_1 = [1]
list_2 = [2]
list_3 = [3]

print(generate_list())
```

result: `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: For example, `list_1 + list_2 + list_3 != [[1], [2], [3]]`

Comment: @ForceBru Edited the code. But anyway, it was a clue for the OP and I supposed he/she would know how to flatten the list(if needed). with `automatically`, I suppose he wants to collect the lists, not to make a robot sitting somewhere waiting for him to add a list and do a magic.

Comment: @Masoud congratulations boy, it worked for me. I never imagined such a heavy loop as a code.

Comment: Relying on a variable name pattern to collect values from your scope is never a good idea. It pollutes your scope, risks collisions and is hard to read.

Answer (score 3):

This problem can actually be solved by a more adapted choice of data structure. If some items are related, they should be stored together inside a container such as a `dict` or a list of lists. Doing so will both make them easier to access and will clean your scope.

```
all_lists = {
    '1': ['1', 'one', 'first', ...],
    '2': ['2', 'two', 'second', ...],
    ...: ...,
    'x': ['x', 'cross']
}
```

You can now access a specific list...

```
list_1 = all_lists['1']
```

... check if an item is inside the lists.

```
if any(item in lst for lst in all_lists.values())
    print('The item is all_lists')
```

... or iterate over all lists with a nested loop.

```
for lst in all_lists.values():
    for item in lst:
        print(item)
```

Comment: The answer is great! But I am too lazy to do that. Thats why I asked this question and Masoud felt my feelings amd gave the best answer for me.

Comment: It's up to you, just keep in mind that a lazy choice right now may be costly in the future